# image hover menu css position dragging other menu items content

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have hover image menu, there's some design problem, when i hover mouse over image i am able to see hover menu but it dragging down other menu items, as far i figured out some issue found here

```
#makesSelector .rangeList { /*position: absolute;*/ }
```

position is required to keep hover menu items on top if i comment position than dragging problem solved but hover design disturbed,
any help would be highly appreciated to fix css position issue.
Take a look as far what i did on Firefox browser

> **Expected solution**: i want hover menu appear same as shown in jsfiddle example and gif but
>
> **don't want dragging other menu items down**

[**jsfiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dwhdwh/r2p0awpx/10/)
[image]

Comment: does your fiddle reproduce the problem? Nothing moves when I hover the broken image links.

Comment: @michael, yup fiddle is working let me try to explain a bit more , take your mouse on "apple " you will see "HP " broken image link will drag down

Comment: hovered over apple, nothing shifted.

Comment: @MichaelCoker i have tested over firefox reproduce the problem, please open fiddle link in Firefox browser in Firefox browser you will see hp drag down when you hover mouse over apple image

Comment: fiddle not working... :(

Comment: @himanshu Fiddle is working on Firefox, the gift screen casting taken by running fiddle on firefox, please open image gif in question

Comment: So what do you want the result to be? You say the other menu items go down when hovering one of them, and you want absolute position. So just use absolute position....

Comment: @ pol when i use  absolute position it making other menu items scroll down and if i comment this position line it change the hover menu design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the "dragging" you will need to add back the absolute positioning on the `#makesSelector .rangeList`.
Use `top: 100%` and `left: 0` to align it. Remove any other margins.
Then, make its parent relative position: `#makesSelector {position:relative;}` and remove `overflow: hidden`.

I've added comments in the code so you can see what was added and what was removed.

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2p0awpx/14/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this it might work for you---

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
.#makesSelector .rangeList {
position:absolute;
right:0;
top:0;
 }
}
```

In some cases giving `right:0` and `left:0` solves `position:absolute` problem for firefox.

Hope this helps!

Comment: now dragging problem solve but there new problem, now hover menu apeear at the right side you can check here -> [https://jsfiddle.net/dwhdwh/r2p0awpx/12/ ] i want to hover menu appear on same position like this [https://jsfiddle.net/dwhdwh/r2p0awpx/10/ ] but no dragging

Comment: i need cross browser solution, i said for jsfiddle example link open in Firefox  jsfiddle example not working in chrome